# Appcache size limit for firefox os/firefox mobile app

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, firefox-os

I am making an web app to run on Firefox OS and Firefox mobile. I want the app to be totally offline after its first run. So, I am using an app cache for offline use. The meat and potatoes is the data, which is stored in a js file with a variable of nested arrays. This file is 13 mb. Using `<html manifest='mymanifest.appcache'>`, I am (obviously) trying to keep this large file as well as all the other files cached. When I run the program in FF desktop, it works correctly and caches the files (after a user confirmation). The app will still run if I disconnect from the internet. However, when running in Firefox Mobile as an app, it wants to load the large file every time the app is started. When I disconnect the internet, the app shows a timeout. Is there something preventing the app from caching the files on FF Mobile when run as an app? My data in the js file is stored like this:

```
var bible = [
   [
      [ 'data here', 'data here', 'data here' ],
      [ 'data here', 'data here', 'data here' ],
      [ 'data here', 'data here', 'data here' ],
      [ 'data here', 'data here', 'data here' ]
   ]
];
```

Comment: Have you tried chunking your data file? You might even need to come up with a different file format, that is more compact than JSON for limited devices like the current Firefox OS ones. Is there a particular error you are getting on Firefox OS? Have you tried debugging your app?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you verify that your manifest.appcache is structured similar to the one here:

https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App/blob/gh-pages/manifest.appcache

You should be fine for data up to 50mb.

Can you confirm for me that you experience the correct behavior on Firefox OS using the App Manager?

Let me know - if you get correct behavior there and it seems like Firefox for Android/FF Mobile is still a problem, I'll pass this along to one of the FF for Android developers and see if they can contribute some advice.